# Using identity theorem - Finding $f(z_n) = sin(z_n)$ but $f(z) \neq \sin(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been thinking about this problem for a while. I'm aware that if I have a sequence $z_n = 1/n$ and I try and find a holomorphic function on the open unit disc such that $f(z_n) = \sin(z_n)$, then $f(z) = \sin(z)$ everywhere because of the identity theorem.

However, if we have a sequence $z_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$, and try and find a holomorphic $f$ s.t. $f(z_n) = \sin(z_n)$, then is it possible that this function is not identically equal to $\sin(z)$ on the unit disc? I've tried to construct such a function but haven't had much luck

Thanks

Comment: what is the difference with the previous situation?

Comment: Why the argument valid for $1/n$ would stop to be valid for $1-1/n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $h(z)=\sin(\pi/(1-z))$ is holomorphic in the open unit disk, and $h(1-1/n)=\sin(n\pi)=0$ for $n \ge 1$. So $f(z)=\sin(z)+h(z)$ is holomorphic in the open unit disk, and equals $\sin(z)$ at $z_{n}=1-1/n$ for all $n \ge 1$, even though $f \ne \sin$.